# Input Method in Vim

Tags: vim

From `:help imcmdline`:

> When set the Input Method is always on when starting to edit a command line, ...

There is no link to `Input Method`. What `Input Method` is referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input method is a program (or os component) which allows keystrokes ore mouse movements (or clicks) to be received as input.  Using a different input method, you can enter characters and symbols that are not on your input device.  (such as a keyboard)  For instance, a different input method would be used for languages that have more [graphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) than there are keys on the keyboard.  In this case, setting `imcmdline` would mean that the current input method is always used when entering command in vim.  The are similar options for different modes as well, such as `iminsert` or `imsearch`.  The function used to get the current input method is set with the `imactivatefunc` option.  Another option is `imdisable` which entirely disables the current input method.

Comment: spelling: `imacivatefunc` -> `imactivatefunc`

Answer (score 0):

Input Method is a special input mode for those who need to type in Chinese, Japanese and other non-Latin layout. IM mode allows to avoid switching your keyboard layout to English when you need to enter some command or cursor motion.